# Which items can I use to boost my hit chance?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, sorcerer, attack-roll

I'm a vryloka cosmic sorcerer. I choose to start with a 16+2 Charisma to get some extra Dex from the point buy and my first three feats were almost entirely focused on boosting defenses and damage (Unarmored Agility, Improved Defenses, Dual Implement Caster), which means my attack bonus is pretty low (+7 at level 5, including Inherent Bonuses).
I already plan getting the Implement focus and the Accuracy competence feat (changing my staff of ruin with an accuracy one might be a good idea then), but I was looking for something I could do *now*, by buying items.

I own a staff of ruin, an artifact staff and the vicious dagger I had before finding the artifact and an amulet of protection.
I also own an amulet of protection that magically turned into a 360gp check when the DM decided to use Inherent Bonuses for our new campaign.

As a party of five, we have almost 2000 gp to spend and it's possible we get an NPC to find us a single uncommon item by winning a skill challenge.

Inherent bonuses also mean that investing in a +2 weapon is not a very good idea, except maybe for my staff of ruin (but I'm not sure the extra damage is worth the price difference).

I can get items from almost any manual, but not from Magazines and settings outher than the Forgotten Realms.

Comment: I'm actually the DM and this is the character of a player with awful English skills. Should I rewrite the question from my point of view, or otherwise state that Zachiel is "my DM"?

Comment: I don't think it matters terribly in this case who the DM or Player is. Ultimately its a question of system optimization.

Answer (score 2):

**Item's generally don't have properties to boost accuracy**

Weapon accuracy is tied to 2 things inherent to the item itself: Weapon proficiency bonus and magic item enhancement bonus. Since you've gtot inherent bonuses on the magic item enhancement bonus doesn't matter and since you are using implements, there is no proficiency bonus to tap into. 4e really relies on feats and stat mods to boost accuracy for your PC.

**Feats: Accuracy > Damage > Defenses in 4e**

You've probably started to get a feel for this as you miss on your (sure to be) damaging attacks. This is accuracy feats are always stressed before damage feats, you generally do half or no damage on a miss which can be quite a big deal. If at all possible talk with your DM about retraining some of your feats now. Those defenses feats and daul implement caster are nice, but you'll be killing the monsters much quicker if you hit (and thus also avoid damage) I would drop both improved defenses and unarmored agility (and pick them up later in heroic as you level)  and instead take the implement expertise for whichever you are using (dagger implements I assume) followed up by a superior implement expertise feat (accurate). Those two feats will boost your to hit by another +2.

Comment: "Item's don't have properties to boost accuracy" -- there are a limited number of items which can increase the frequency of your hits based on their properties and powers rather than their enhancement bonus. `Battle Staff`, for example, crits on a 19-20 (for weapons attacks) and has a daily reroll power (for melee attacks only). `Spirit Reliquary` has a daily to add an item bonus to your next roll of pretty much any d20. `Manual of Puissant Skill` has an encounter power to get +2 to your next attack roll. And so on. Getting rerolls is more common, but getting bonuses exists.

Comment: @BrianS edited to reflect mostly, Expanded crit range is not increased accuracy. Yes your 19 crit will hit something you may have missed, but unless you have absolutely no stats for the attack or are fighting a monster way above your level the difference between a 19 hitting as a crit or missing as a regular is so terribly minor.

Comment: Also I interpreted his question as looking for ways to permanently boost accuracy, not a daily item power that gave a minor bonus to 1 attack.

Comment: Fair enough (and Battle Staff isn't likely to be useful to this particular character anyway, since it only helps weapon attacks and melee attacks, and the character is a sorcerer), however when it comes down to "I need to buy an item to up my accuracy", something like a +2 once per encounter seems pretty good, especially if you can use it with an implement power against a NAC defense and inflict some kind of status effect.

Comment: @BrianS the book could be a good idea. On the other items, Joshua is right.